# Border у пустого span

Tags: html, css, border, divider

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста нужно сделать вертикальный разделитель пунктирный без изображений с помощью border-left css, если есть содержимое в span то все работает, как сделать чтобы span был пустой и рамка отображалась? спасибо.

```
<span style="border-left: 2px solid #000; height: 100%;"></span>
```

Не выводит т.к пустой.

Comment: разделитель чего ? списка ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых спану необходимо задать свойство display: inline-block; иначе задать высоту вы ему не сможете. А чтобы высота работала в процентах, то все родители так же должны иметь свойство height в процентах поэтому задавайте ширину в пикселях либо в других единицах. Если покажите код можно будет найти решение конкретно под вашу разметку.

Comment: Благодарю, понял свои ошибки)

Answer (score 2):

`span` - инлайновый тег, border действует для блочных элементов. как и 100% высота просто так не будет работать, нужно чтобы у родителя тоже был `height: 100%`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span style="display: block; border-left: 2px solid #000; height: 100%;"></span>
```

пунктиром

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span style="display: block; border-left: 2px dashed #000; height: 100%;"></span>
```

Comment: пунктирчиком бы :)